# Data Transformation in R, append column name into row and unlist from data frame

Tags: r

I create data frame, called 'inputData', from JSON.

And I want transform data into outputData style to draw graph using ggplot.

How can I transform data look like this?

```
inputData.
       A       B
1  a, 1, 2  b, 3, 4
2  c, 5, 6  d, 7, 8

outputData.
  x y z w
1 a 1 2 A
2 c 5 6 A
3 b 3 4 B
4 d 7 8 B
```

-- append --

I append real code to generate the data for your convenience.

```
> if(!require('rjson')){
    install.packages('rjson')
    library('rjson')
  }

> rawData<-fromJSON('[{"id":"A", "list":[{"x":"a", "y":1, "z":2}, {"x":"c", "y":5, "z":6}]}, {"id":"B", "list":[{"x":"b", "y":3, "z":4}, {"x":"d", "y":7, "z":8}]}]')
> data1<- as.data.frame(sapply(rawData, function(x){
  list(
    id = x$id,         
    vlist = x$list 
    )
  }))
> colnames(data1) <- sapply(data1, function(x){x$id})
> inputData <- as.data.frame(sapply(data1, function(x){ x$vlist }))
```

Comment: Does your `Data1` actually contains the word "list" in it? I.e. , is this your data set `Data1 <- data.frame(A = c("list(x=1, y=2, z=3)",  "list(x=7, y=8, z=9)"), B = c("list(x=4, y=5, z=6)", "list(x=10, y=11, z=12)"))`?

Comment: Yes, JSON parser generates that data for nested array.

Comment: But data is a little different, inputData$A is "[1] list(x=1, y=2, z=3) list(x=7, y=8, z=9)" as your i.e, but in my case inputData$A is "[[1]] [[1]]$x [1] 1 [[1]$y [1] 2 [[1]$z [1] 3 [[2]] [[2]]$x [1] 7 [[2]$y [1] 8 [[2]$z [1] 9".

Comment: Can you post the actual output of `Data1` into the original question please?

Comment: I append actual output in my question, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce that. Also, what is `inputData` and how is it related to `Data1`? I.e., where are these "a","b", etc letters came from?

Comment: Sorry, I append source code to reproduce that. And inputData is Data1 in my first question. and I changed example to explain the list is not vector. Please see my source code to make inputData. I want to transform inputData data frame as Data2 looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
cbind(do.call(rbind.data.frame, unlist(inputData, F)), 
      w = rep(names(inputData), each = nrow(inputData)))
#   x y z w
#A1 a 1 2 A
#A2 c 5 6 A
#B1 b 3 4 B
#B2 d 7 8 B
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel it's hard to handle data using R is not easy than other languages, because I'm not good at R.